# Angular 2: appending child routes dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to know if it is possible to dynamically append child routes at run time, from lets say a service...?

Given:

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: GloriousComponent,
        children: [
           { path: 'path1', component: Child1Component },
           { path: 'path2', component: Child2Component },
           { path: 'path3', component: Child3Component },
        ]
    }
];
```

Could I remove the children of the ' ' path and somehow get a reference to the const routes and then later on dynamically append children to the ' ' path?

Something along the lines of...

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: GloriousComponent           
    }
];

routes[''].appendChildren(
        [
           { path: 'path1', component: Child1Component },
           { path: 'path2', component: Child2Component },
           { path: 'path3', component: Child3Component },
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Dynamically you mean on bootstrap? or when app is runned?

Comment: I mean at run time, I updated my question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9527 look at this

Comment: But why you want to do it on runtime? can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr, that link was helpful. I am adding routes at runtime because they can change based on user behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently modifying is not supported but you can maintain a list of routes yourself and then call

```
this.router.resetConfig(routes)
```

to load a new set of routes into the router.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, achieving this is easy. If you want to add a child route to the current route,

```
const childRoute =  {path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent} 
this.route.routeConfig.children.push(childRoute)
```

where "this.route" is from the ActivatedRoute injected in the constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
```

Alternatively, if you just want to add a new route to the router config, do this:

```
newRoute = {path: 'somePath', component: SomeComponent}
this.router.config.push(newRoute)
```

Comment: Do you need to run an update method on the child routes when you use the first one? I have tried this and it didnt work @Rip3rs